# General rule for finding radius of convergence of $\sum\limits_na_nx^{n^2}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

> What will be the radius of convergence of $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^{n^2}\ ?$$

My Try : By Hadamard's Law  $$\textrm{Radius} = \frac {1} {\limsup|a_n|^{1/n^2}}.$$

Is this correct?

If we can not use this formulae then how would we find the radius? Can we apply Ratio Test?

Comment: Note that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^{n^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_nx^{n}$ where $b_{n^2}=a_n$ and $b_n=0$ for $n$ not a square.

Comment: Yes That's how I applied Cauchy - Hadamard..@vrugtehagel

Comment: It's not quite correct, the limit need not exist. It's $$R = \frac{1}{\limsup \lvert a_n\rvert^{1/n^2}}.$$

Comment: Yes you are  correct..But if we can not apply this ,is there anyway to find the radius?@DanielFischer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general way would be to investigate the convergence of the series by any method you know for series, then see which values of $x$ satisfy the condition you get.

For example, you ask about ratio test ...  Compute
$$
\lim_n \frac{a_{n+1}x^{(n+1)^2}}{a_n x^{n^2}} = \lim_n \frac{a_{n+1}x^{2n+1}}{a_n} ,
$$
an answer that may involve $x$, then see for which $x$ this limit is $\lt 1$.